# select NULL or BLANK or misc fields

Tags: oracle

I have a table where in the column have null values, blank spaces and misc values like !!, %% etc

I would like to select all the rows that do not have the Country ID.

How to select rows that do not have a Country ID?

Here is the SQL FIDDLE

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/bf3688/3

This is what I tried

```
SELECT * FROM PLAYER_TABLE WHERE COUNTRY_ID IS NULL OR LENGTH(TRIM (COUNTRY_ID)) = 0
```

Expected Output

```
PLAYER_ID   COUNTRY_ID

65  
98  (null)
99  (null)
13  !!
15  (null)
16  $$
18  
19  (null)
75  (null)
```

Comment: How would you exactly define "has a country ID" ? Can this be looked up in another table? Is `XY` a valid country ID?

Comment: @cyberbrain Yes, XY a valid country ID, So I'm looking other rows that has NUll, blank spaces, and misc like !!, @@ ** ETC

Answer (score 1):

1. Readable version: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/bf3688/5

```
SELECT * 
FROM PLAYER_TABLE 
WHERE COUNTRY_ID IS NULL 
OR regexp_replace(COUNTRY_ID,'[^A-Z]') is null
```

2. Fast version: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/bf3688/6

```
SELECT * 
FROM PLAYER_TABLE 
WHERE COUNTRY_ID IS NULL 
OR translate(COUNTRY_ID,'0ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ','0') is not null
```

Comment: In fact you can even delete the first predicate `COUNTRY_ID IS NULL`, but it makes filters faster in case of nulls

Answer (score 1):

Use `NOT REGEXP_LIKE(COUNTRY_ID, '[A-Z][A-Z]')`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM PLAYER_TABLE
WHERE COUNTRY_ID IS NULL
OR NOT REGEXP_LIKE(COUNTRY_ID, '[A-Z][A-Z]')
```

See [live demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1ef079/2).

The regex means "two capital letters" so it's easy to understand the SQL: "where country_id is not two capital letters".